# Android onItemClickListener not working (despite trying all other SO solutions)

Tags: java, android

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times on this site but none of the answers were of any help.

Here is my code in my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_claim);

    ListView list = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.claim_list));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.claim_item_menu, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_claim_menu_item) {
                        deleteFile(adapter.getClaims().remove(position).getId());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(SelectClaimActivity.this, ViewClaimActivity.class)
                .putExtra(OLD_CLAIM_KEY, (Parcelable) adapter.getClaims().get(position)),
                EDIT_CLAIM_CODE
            );
        }
    });
}
```

My XML for the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/claim_list"
    >

</ListView>
```

And the XML for the list items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:longClickable="true">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/claim_id"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/claim_created_date"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the code that inflates the item views:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Claim claim = claims.get(position);

    TextView idView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_id);
    TextView dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_created_date);

    idView.setText(claim.getId());
    dateView.setText(FORMAT.format(claim.getCreationDate()));

    return convertView;
}
```

The onItemLongClickListener works perfectly, but the onItemClickListener never fires (confirmed with the debugger).

As you can see my code is very simple.

Things I have tried (based on other SO answers) that haven't worked:

1. setting android:focusable="false" on the TextViews contained in the item view (my understanding is that this is the default anyway)
2. setting android:focusableInTouchMode="false" on the TextViews contained in the item view
3. setting android:clickable="false" on those TextViews
4. setting android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the LinearLayout in the item view XML
5. setting android:clickable="true" on the LinearLayout in the item view XML (this one seems weird - removing the android:longClickable="true" means the long clicks no longer work, but this doesn't seem to do the trick for regular clicks)
6. doing all of the above in the getView() method instead

Comment: have you tried to set **OnClickListener** to *convertView* inside the **getView** function? you can work it that way and I find it simpler

Comment: My understanding is that that is less efficient? And I feel like the OnItemClickListener approach _should_ work, so I would like to use it!

Comment: Oh my God! I had the same issue, but much much weirder, the function would fire only in regular mode, but whenever I start `ActionMode` that callback never fires! and the only difference in the code was me showing and hiding a view inside each of the list items based on the mode. Couldn't figure it out, ended up changing my design. It made zero sense!

Comment: if you remove the **onItemLongClickListener** does **onItemClickListener** work? try changing their ordering maybe set **onItemClickListener** than set **onItemLongClickListener**